# python tkinter: destroy() not working after using threading.Timer()

Tags: python, tkinter

Code Part 1

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import threading

c1 = "#262626"

root = Tk()
root.overrideredirect(True)
root.configure(bg=c1)

def destroy():
    global root
    root.destroy()

def pr():
    print("asd")
    destroy()

def animation():
    threading.Timer(0.01, pr).start()

animation()
root.mainloop()
```

after the destroy () command has worked, the window is closed, but the program continues to work, you can disable it only with the help of the task manager or CMD, but there's no any errors.

Code Part 2

```
login = Tk()

img = Image.open(selfDir + "\\ok.png").resize((50, 50), Image.ANTIALIAS)
test = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
label1 = Label(login, image=test, bg=c1)
label1.image = test
label1.place(x=330, y=145, width=50, height=50)

login.mainloop()
```

if I run this part after the first one, I see an error:

*tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "image" command: application has been destroyed*

but if I run only this part, without the first one, then it works and I can see the photo in the window

So the problem is.
I need to close window after **threading.Timer()**
Then i need to open window, with an image

Comment: first of `global root` is not needed, second, don't call `tkinter` methods from other threads, you can schedule functions with the `after` method. Third, what do you mean by using the code part 2 after part 1? is part 2 run right after the mainloop or what?

Comment: i mean, when i run only the 2nd part, it works perfect, but if i run the 2nd part after "root.mainloop()", after root.destroy, i see the error (my english is not very well) || 

i just tried "after(1000, pr)", it worked successfuly, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

i just need to write
`root.after(10, pr)`
instead of
`threading.Timer(0.01, pr).start()`

special thanks to [Matiiss](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14531062/matiiss)